# How to find the uppercase letter by using ascii code in JAVA?

Tags: java

I want to implement my version to toUppercase function in java. I pass a char and it need to return the uppercase of this char.

I don't want to use builtin methods such as Char, String class or regex.

I try to do it with ascii code but not sure how...

```
int ascii = (int) 'a';
```

I have the ascii code but how to figure out the corrent uppercase?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: look at the decimal representation of the ascii characters. `A` is `65` and `a` is `97`. `B` is `66` and `b` is `98`. Do you see the pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract `32` from the `ascii` value. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c = 'a';
    System.out.println(toUpperCase(c));
}
private static char toUpperCase(char c) {
    return (char) (c - 32);
}
```

Output:

```
A
```

Comment: Nice! But you don't need to cast `c` to an `int`. You could just `return (char) (c - 32);`

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `char` is a 16-bit integral type. You can add the difference between `'A'` and `'a'` then cast to `int` (after first checking the value is in the expected range). Something like,

```
char ch = 'a'; // <-- For example...
char CH = ch;
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
    CH = (char) (ch + ('A' - 'a'));
}
System.out.printf("%c %c%n", ch, CH);
```

Output

```
a A
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting 32 if its lower case would work.

```
public class Main {

    public static char toUpperCase(char ch) {
        if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) {
            return (char) (ch - 32);
        } else return ch;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(toUpperCase('a'));
    }
}
```